# how can I make the anchor tag call function in flask

Tags: python, flask

how can I make the anchor tag call function in flask 
I have this code

```
                  <a href="/logout" style="display: block;" method ="POST">Log out</a>
```

I should call a logout method in it

```
#logout
@app.route('/logout',methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    user = mongo.db.users.filter_by(email=str(current_user.email)).first()

    user.is_active = False
    db.session.commit()
    session.clear()

    return render_template('index.html')
```

but I GOT THIS ERROR Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: as I know `<a>` can't send `POST` - it always sends `GET`. You have to use `<form method="POST" action="/logout"><button>Log out</button></form>`

Comment: this is the error msg :

Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: why do you want to send it as `POST`? Why don't use normal `GET` ?

Comment: Thank you, using GET have worked

Comment: you should use  `href="{{ url_for('app.logout') }}"`

Answer (score 1):

As I know `<a>` can't send `POST` - it sends it as `GET` - so don't use `method=["POST"]`

```
 <a href="/logout" style="display: block;">Log out</a> 

 @app.route('/logout')
```

---

If you really need to send `POST` then you have to use `<form>`

```
 <form method="POST" action="/logout">
    <button type="submit">Log out</button>
 </form>
```

but if you don't send any extra data then there is no need to use `POST`